# ROCKET CHAT ADMIN PANEL -- Push notifications not working when click on Send Test Push

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apn, rocket.chat

```
Rocket.Chat app version: 3.2.0 (223)
Rocket.Chat server version: 0.72.3  
Device: iPhone 7/iOS 12.1
```

I have done all the setup mentioned in below link.

https://rocket.chat/docs/administrator-guides/notifications/push-notifications

[image]

**But every time I click on Send a test Push I got an error saying
There are no tokens for this user**

Also, I have checked View Logs while logging in to the app.

```
Push: Got push token from the app: {
    token: {
        apn: '45a24c27b9a1029da2c06f0ddbe99dbf6ec072988ffe260fa764d1f5eb2c4d47'
    },
    userId: 'eiBnnCawfhfpBxKFD',
    id: '2661F96CFB3B4A51866E0FD468759152',
    appName: 'com.resellcalendar',
    metadata: {}
}
```

All the data seems to be sent properly.

> **Note:** I am checking with my own server

Comment: Did you restart the server after making the changes?

Comment: Yes I restarted the server after making changes.

Comment: You can set debug or production to false depending on which one you're testing, then restart the server. So keep debug on true and set production to false if you're testing with debug.

Comment: And I presume you have recompiled the mobile apps with your own certificates from your own Apple and Google accounts, correct?

Comment: Yes Of course, I did

Comment: I had the same problem - solev it through installing the app from Google Playstore. Before I had installed the app from F-Droid. That's annoying

Answer (score 0):

If you work on own chat implementation on mobile, probably you should register your token to receive push notifications

Post request

api/v1/push.token

with body

type : "gcm"/"apn" (android/ios)

value: "authToken" from login

appName:"Main"